# Selecting results for different users

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a sql query for different ids.
Something like

```
    SELECT SUM(cost) FROM sales
    WHERE id = "multiple ids"
```

I want the sum of the sales of each person separately but I can't seem to get it to work.
I tried using `WHERE IN` but that returns a single query for the sum of everything.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY` to aggregate `SUM(cost)` for each person.

```
    SELECT id, SUM(cost) FROM sales
    WHERE id IN (
         1, 2, 3, 4
    )
    GROUP BY id
```